# Show Dialog in GCM onMessage()

Tags: android, dialog, google-cloud-messaging, android-context

I am implementing GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) into my App.

I set it up all like in the Google Tutorial, and it works so far.

I display a notification in the notification-bar when `onMessage` when the `GCMIntentService` gets called.

Now I have a method that tells me if the app is in foreground or not.
When the app is in background it shows the notification in the bar with no problem.

But how could I show a Dialog to the user?

When I call:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

where context is the given context from `onMessage()`, I of course this error:

> _Notification.showPopUp() Error: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token null is not for an application

So I tried to replace the context with `MainActivity.this`, for this purpose I saved it in a static variable; but when i now run it, nothing happens, no error, no dialog appears.

My code for the dialog:

```
private static AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog;

private static void showPopUp(Context context,String kind, String resource_name, Integer resource_id)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

Log.e("TEST","alert.show()");
}
```

The last log: alert.show() gets displayed in logcat, but no error.

Spec: 
Runnning on the device (Galaxy S2)
Android 4.0.3

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code, or does anybody knows some workaround?

Edit:

The part where I save my `MainActivity.this`:

```
private static Context context_forshowingPopUp = null;
```

onCreate

```
//Set the context for showing a popup View
_Notification.setContext_forshowingPopUp(this);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext_forshowingPopUp());

public static Context getContext_forshowingPopUp() 
{
    return context_forshowingPopUp;
}

public static void setContext_forshowingPopUp(Context context_forshowingPopUp) 
{
    _Notification.context_forshowingPopUp = context_forshowingPopUp;
}
```

Comment: For the record: if the app is not in foreground, you can still use the notification area. See class NotificationManager.

Comment: Yes, i know but it seems not very logic that the user gets a notification in the notification bar when he is allready in the app. Are there any infos in the android design patterns about this use-case?

Comment: Just maintain the pointer to a current activity in some statically accessible place. Set it in onResume() of every activity in the app, clear in onPause(). Helps if all activities derive from a custom common base.

Comment: I tryed it it doesn´t work! :/. any other ideas?

Comment: If i save my activity in a static variable and i wan´t to sho the dialog, nothing happens, no error, no logcat entry or something else.

Comment: Have you tried to debug that spot? Are you using the activity context to invoke the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

you must use  YourCurrentActivity.this as a context while building Alertdialog. You can solve like below .

first class :

```
  public class Config{
     public static Context context;

    }
```

when your activity creates , just set Config.contex

```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      Config.context=this;
    ...}
    //other stuffs

      }
```

In OnMessage

```
   showPopUp(Config.context,kind, resource_name, resource_id);
```

Comment: i have a private static Context context_forshowingPopUp; and i do exact the same thing than you. But it doesnt work. i will update my question, to show this part. thanks

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.view.ViewRootImpl) {41929ee8} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread - Is what I get in log cat with this solution

Comment: I'd say this is another reason why global state is wrong: keeping a reference to the main activity doesn't guarantee that this activity will stay alive at the time it would be needed.